# Subtracting two time ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two timeranges

```
Fri, 02 Aug 2019 10:09:58 UTC +00:00..Fri, 02 Aug 2019 23:59:59 UTC +00:00
Fri, 02 Aug 2019 11:09:58 UTC +00:00..Fri, 02 Aug 2019 12:09:58 UTC +00:00
```

What's the simplest way to subtract the second from the first so I get

```
[
   Fri, 02 Aug 2019 10:09:58 UTC +00:00..Fri, 02 Aug 2019 11:09:58 UTC +00:00,     
   Fri, 02 Aug 2019 12:09:58 UTC +00:00..Fri, 02 Aug 2019 23:59:59 UTC +00:00
]
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the second range is always included in the first? Will the second always cut the first in two parts? Or ist is possible that the ranges only intersect or do not overlap at all? If so, how to handle such cases?

Comment: Yes, it's always included.

Comment: You will earn at least one upvote if you address @spickerman’s comment by editing your question to state that second range falls wholly within the first.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
range_1 = (Time.parse('2019-08-02 10:09:58 UTC') .. Time.parse('2019-08-02 23:59:59 UTC'))
range_2 = (Time.parse('2019-08-02 11:09:58 UTC') .. Time.parse('2019-08-02 12:09:58 UTC'))

[(range_1.begin..range_2.begin), (range_2.end..range_1.end)]
#=> [2019-08-02 10:09:58 UTC..2019-08-02 11:09:58 UTC, 2019-08-02 12:09:58 UTC..2019-08-02 23:59:59 UTC]
```

Comment: `[(range_1.begin..range_2.begin), (range_2.end.. range_1.end)]`

Comment: You have been faster ;)